# Edit particular content in XML

Tags: xml, powershell

I am new to Powershell.I have to edit the line "connection.username" with USER_AUTH_PARIS.I have to edit an xml file using powershell. My xml file looks like.

I have tried with xpath, but couldn't get the expected result

the file should be edited with USER_AUT_PARIS instead of USER_AUT

Comment: Please edit the question and include your XPath too. Then we can explain what's wrong with it and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML and XPath are case sensitive, so `Select-XML $xmlopen -Xpath "//Property Name"` doesn't work. First off, it should be `//property` and the attribute part is incorrect too.

Use proper case and access attribute with `[@attribute='value']` syntax like so,

```
Select-Xml $x -Xpath "//property[@name='connection.username']"
Node     Path        Pattern
----     ----        -------
property InputStream //property[@name='connection.username']
```

To modify, select the proper node and assign new value into its `Node.#text` element. Mind the quotes around `'#text'`, as `#` is the comment character in Powershell. Skipping error check, like so

```
(Select-Xml $x -Xpath "//property[@name='connection.username']").Node.'#text' = 'user_auth_paris'
$x.save([console]::out)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
<InitFile version="1.0">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.username">user_auth_paris</property>
  </session-factory>
</InitFile>
```